Why does John 19:17 include the words, "which in Aramaic is called Golgotha"?
John 19:17 ESV

"and he went out, bearing his own cross, to the place called The Place of a Skull, which in Aramaic is called Golgotha." [My emphasis]

Some translations don't put "Aramaic" but instead "Hebrew" e.g., Berean S.B.; NASB 1977; Good News.
Some put "Aramaic" e.g., CEV; ESV; NIV. I am not asking about this difference.
Who might be helped by knowing that the PLace of a Skull was Golgotha whether that is in Aramaic or Hebrew?
Was John targeting a particular audience with the information that the Place of a Skull in Aramaic was Golgotha?
What can we learn by John putting the words "which in Aramaic is called Golgotha"? e.g., Does it tell us about the people to whom John was writing?

John did have a habit of providing translation or simple explanations of Hebrew and Aramaic terms or names in Greek.
Some examples include:

Sea of Galilee – Sea of Tiberius (6:1; 21:1), Cephas – Peter (1:42),
Messiah – Anointed (1:40-41; 4:25), Rabbi – Teacher (1:38), Siloam –
Sent (9:7), Rabboni – Teacher (20:16). Strikingly, several times he translates Greek back into Hebrew/Aramaic as well,  such as: Skull Hill – Golgotha (19:17) and Stone Pavement – Gabbatha (19:13).

The simple answer is that John was likely written to a variety of Israelite groups.

There exists a consensus among scholars that the language of Jesus and
his disciples was Aramaic. Aramaic was the common language of Judea in
the first century AD. [1]


Aramaic was the common language of the Eastern Mediterranean during
and after the Neo-Assyrian, Neo-Babylonian, and Achaemenid empires
(722–330 BC) and remained a common language of the region in the first
century AD. [1]

What we know from this:

The Gospel of John was written by one familiar with Aramaic, but also
fluent in Koine Greek - the international language of the day. The
audience of this Gospel is universal. The perspective is accessible to
all readers, rather than tailored to a particular cultural background
like the other three Gospels. [2]

The name appears in all of the gospels except Luke:

Gagūltā Aramaic, means 'skull'. The name appears in all of the gospels
except Luke, which calls the place simply Kranion (Κρανίον) 'the
Skull' in Greek, with no Semitic counterpart. The name 'Calvary' is
taken from the Latin Vulgate translation, Calvaria. [1]
In Aramaic, it could be ܓܓܘܠܬܐ. Though this word has the Aramaic final
form -ta / -tha, it is otherwise also closer to the Hebrew word for
skull, gulgolet גולגולת, than to the Aramaic form. [1]

What we notice in the gospel of John is that he interrupts the narrative to explain certain Jewish customs or the meaning of certain Aramaic words.
It would make sense that in these parts he's not tailoring to a Jewish audience. If it was a Jewish audience, he likely wouldn't have had to explain these things.
Based on the evidence presented, I would conclude that the Gospel of John was likely not written for a Jewish audience, or at least not a predominantly Jewish one. If the intended audience was Jewish, they would likely have been Hellenistic Jews who had lost their Hebrew cultural heritage and thus required frequent explanatory notes from the Jewish apostle John.

I suspect that what you are driving at is that the gospel could be talking to those who know the place by experience, by the name of Golgotha; but, being Greek, might not be aware that this meant the Skull.
It's possible. But I wouldn't make that inference. I do NOT think it tells us about the people to whom the gospel is addressed. (Alas. I would like to know that too.)
You may like to hear what Epiphanius says: Panarion iii, 5,1 (Ag. Tatianists):

And so we must be surprised at someone (like Tatian) who knows— as I
too have found in the literature—that our Lord Jesus Christ was crucified on Golgotha, nowhere else than where Adam’s body lay
buried. 19 (2) For after leaving Paradise, living opposite it for a
long time and growing old, Adam later came and died in this place, I
mean Jerusalem, and was buried there, on the site of Golgotha. (3)
This is probably the way the place, which means “Place of a Skull,”
got its name, since the contour of the site bears no resemblance to
a skull. (4) Neither is it on some peak so that this can be
interpreted as a skull, as we say of < the > head’s position on a
body. Nor is it on a height.

It is clear that Epiphanius knows the place believed to be the site of the crucifixion, and it looks nothing like a skull. I think he is sceptical about Adam's skull being on the same site  - though the story certainly has symbolism and color.
My own opinion is that John was using a name which pre-existed his gospel, perhaps in a vorlage. And that "skull" is a rationalization. (Though a good one. גלגלת = skull; the final aleph = the.)
It's an interesting word. Gilgal (name of a place) signifies a stone circle. In Greek LXX, it is variously vocalized: Galgal, Golgol.
It can mean a wheel, rolling. Cf also gal = heap, wave.
You may also be interested to know that the word gilgul גלגול is used to mean re-incarnation of souls in Jewish mysticism. If that connection sounds outlandish to you, you may not be aware that some early Christian sects (eg Naasenes) viewed the meaning of Jesus' resurrection this way, as offering an escape route to God for the soul from the cycle of rebirths.
I am not going to over-interpret.
But I would like to direct you to a parallel. When John tells us about "a place called The Stone Pavement [Λιθόστρωτον], and in Aramaic Gabbatha" (John 19.13) - Gabbatha categorically DOES NOT MEAN pavement. It means a raised platform, probably a gibbet; it could also mean a high place in the sense of hill. DYOR.
What amazed me most about this anomaly is that no-one seemed ever to have checked!!
My conclusion about Gabbatha is that the word was used in a previous telling of the story, now lost, probably as the place where Jesus was hanged, right there in front of Pilate saying "Behold the man". Now it survives as a putative name for the "Pavement" which may indeed have been a feature which was familiar to people. (Tho honestly I doubt it. I trace both unusual words, lithostratos and Gabbatha/Bagathon to the Book of Esther.)
My point is: I would pay attention to the word Golgotha, not to the alleged meaning, which is a plausible rationalization.
